# Clickable table row expect last td and expand table row on last td

Tags: jquery, html-table, css-selectors

I have a table, the table row should be clickable 'except' for the last td in that row. So when clicked it opens a new window to a new URL.

However in that same table row, the last td needs to be clickable also to expand the table row for more details. At the moment I have this working but rather than having the one td clickable the whole row is (which I don't want).

The code for the expand table row is: -

```
$("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
        $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
        $("#report tr:first-child").show();

        $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
            $(this).next("tr").toggle();
            $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");

        });
```

So overall I need the row clickable expect for the last td.

The last td I want to be able to expand the table row by clicking on that td NOT the whole row?

Any help would be great - I know what I need I just don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of applying the `click` event to the entire `tr`, you could apply it to the relevant cells instead like so:

```
$("#report tr.odd td:not(:last-child)")
```

That would select every `td` in the row except for the last one in the row.

To then access the next `tr`, you'll need to change that selector too:

```
$(this).parent().next("tr").toggle();
```

This will get the parent of the `td` you've clicked on (a `tr`) then find the next one. If the `.arrow` class is applied to a tr, the same needs to happen there:

```
$(this).parent().find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
```

Comment: I need the row clickable except the last td, once clicked on open a new URL. I have added: $('#report tr td:not(:last-child)').click(function () { OPEN URL }); which has no effect. The last td in the row needs to expand the table row to show more, the code in my first code expands the row, using jExpand? Nothing has any effect.

Comment: // Open new URL clicking on Row execpt on last child
   $("#report tr.odd td:not(:last-child)").click(function () {
    alert("HELLO WORLD!");
   });
   
   // Expand row clicking on last child only / not on whole row
            $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
            $("#report tr:first-child").show();
            
            $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
    
            });

Comment: Updated answer on how to get to the necassary `tr`'s

Comment: Kind of working but the wrong way round. I need the whole tr except the last td to be clickable and open a URL. Then last td in the tr needs to expand the row to show more details. When i apply your code its kind of doing the opposite. Sorry, im just starting to learn jQuery as you can tell! thanks

Comment: If it's doing the opposite, then what I've done is used the `:not()` selector to not select the last td, if this is the one you want to select, you can remove it and end up with this: `$("#report tr.odd td:last-child")`

Comment: Cheers, only issue now is the code i have for when i click on the tr except the last row it should open a URL. However it still shows the alert when i click on the last td. // Make all but last td clickable
   $("#report  tr:not(:last-child)").click(function () {
    alert("All Rows but last row!");
   });

Comment: The code in your comment clearly has an `alert()` inside the function, you'd need to replace that with something like `window.location = 'http://www.google.com';`

Comment: Im just using the alert for testing for now, however i cant seem to get the alert to work for every td apart from the last one, in other works i dont want the alert to appear in the very last td in the row. My code works, but it seems to do the whole row! $("#report tr:not(:last-child)").click(function () {
    alert("All Rows but last row!");
   });